# Fullscreen UIImage in Swift 4

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a UICollectionView with cells that contain UIImages. Here is my didSelectIndex method to grab the image and fullscreen it.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let media = self.media[indexPath.row]
    guard let photoURL = URL(string: media.photoURL) else { return }

    // Get the image from the cache
    if let image = mediaCache.object(forKey: photoURL.absoluteString as AnyObject) as? UIImage {
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
        imageView.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
        imageView.backgroundColor = .black
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true

        let dismissTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissFullscreenImage))
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(dismissTap)

        self.view.addSubview(imageView)
    }
}
```

However, changing the content mode from scaleAspectFill to scaleAspectFit doesn't solve the issue. The image doesn't fit inside the UIImageView frame. [image: The first picture is the scaleAspectFill version.] [image: The second picture is the scaleAspectFit version.]

Comment: You need the image view to be higher then the screen (I think), maybe consider putting to into a `UIScrollView`, or do some self cropping yourself or letting the image view exceed the bounds of the view/window ... as a bunch of early morning thoughts :P

Comment: I might consider making the `UIImageView` as large as the image, then manually centre the image in on the screen, not sure that would give you the desired result, still think a `UIScrollView` might be a better solution

Comment: I might also consider using a second, dedicated `UIViewController` which could be presented as "over current screen"